# Linkedin retrieve full profile details?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I want to integrate the Linkedin API and fetch all the details (Education ,detail..)

But When I pass **r_fullprofile** in the grant access. I am getting following error.

> authorization failed Error Domain=LIALinkedInERROR Code=1

I have done the code as below :

```
- (LIALinkedInHttpClient *)client {
  LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication applicationWithRedirectURL:@"http://www.google.com"
                                                                                  clientId:@"XXXXXXX"
                                                                              clientSecret:@"XXXXX"
                                                                                     state:@"DCEEFWF45453sdffef424"
                                                                             grantedAccess:@[@"r_fullprofile",@"r_emailaddress"]];
  return [LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application presentingViewController:nil];
}
```

Comment: have you ticked r_fullprofile while creating your app in linkedin developer account??

Answer (score 1):

May be you are not aware of the developer programe changes done by LinkedIn as explained in ***https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition***

[image]